# FFMPEG want to show black screen once video ends

Tags: ffmpeg

I am currently horizontally stacking multiple videos. Once a video is finished, it shows the last frame it ended at. I want it to show a black screen/frame once a video finishes. Is there an option in ffmpeg that lets you do that?

Comment: t is better to use tpad to add a single black frame at the end. What' your full command?

Comment: @Gyan this is the full command i'm using at the moment https://pastebin.com/7BaXJVuS

Comment: @Gyan but with that scale filter being set for each video.

Comment: @Gyan got anything for me?

Comment: Add `stop=1` to the tpad filters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter:v "fade=t=out:st=15:d=5:color=0x000000" -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mp4
```

This starts the fadeout at 15 seconds, 5 seconds to fade out.

You'll have to do this for each video if you want both to fade to black. You can set the time you want the video to start fading by changing the 15. The 5 is for the length of the fade.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Will this filter need to be set for each video that is going to be horizontally stacked? And does it start fading at 15 seconds remaining and then fades out completely within 5 seconds?